# How override cursor:text in the asp:menu for non-clickable items?

Tags: asp.net, menu, mouse-cursor

I have a menu control on the master page. The datasource for the menu is a websitemap.

```
E.g., 
       HOME
            Page1 (clickable)
            Page2
                SubPage1A (clickable)
                SubPage2B
                   SubPageSubPage1 (clickable)
                   SubPageSubPage2 (clickable)
            Page3
                SubPage1C (clickable)
```

What i want to do is to make clickable(i mean when u click on this link you go to some url) only pages on the bottom level.
So, from this example clickable pages would be : Page1, SubPage1A, SubPageSubPage1, SubPageSubPage2 and SubPage1C.

To make other pages non-clickable i remove "url" attribute from the websitemap xml. 
For now, when i open the page i see the cursor:text style assigned for all non-clickable items (it's 'I') and cursor:pointer (hand) for clickable items.

I know that i can manage cursor styles assigning them for . But that works only for a bunch of items in a hiearchy. But i need to have different cursor styles at the same hierarchy level.

Are there any way to override the cursor:text style by any other for non-clickable items and keep the hand cursor for clickable?

Thanks

Comment: Did you figure out your problem?

Comment: No, i didn't. I just made a hand cursor for all menu items.

Answer (score 4):

Menu items with submenus render as a hyperlink with href="#". In the CSS, select those hyperlinks as shown below.

```
<asp:Menu ...>
    <StaticMenuItemStyle    CssClass="MenuItemClass" />
    <DynamicMenuItemStyle   CssClass="MenuItemClass" />
</asp:Menu>


a.MenuItemClass[href="#"]
{
    cursor: default !important;
}
```

Tested on FF 3.6.15, Google Chrome 10, Safari 5.0.3, IE 8 and IE 8 in IE7 mode on Windows 7.

Comment: I opted for force it explicitly with `cursor: pointer !important;` And got the desired result.